# TinyMCE and fancybox interaction error

Tags: javascript, tinymce, fancybox, rte

I'm trying to use tinyMCE on a textarea that i display using jquery fancybox. I've tried using the tinyMCE jQuery plugin , the default download version of tinyMCE and the full download version of tinyMCE

the first time i open the form (the form is shown via fancybox) everything works as intended;
if i cancel the action and try to open the form again, the textarea is disabled but the tinyMCE controls are still shown, only they don't work.

this is the code for the form i use. it is shown via fancybox :

```
<div id="add-task" class="form-container">
<form method="POST" action="/task-add">
    <input type="hidden" name="project" id="add-task-id" value=""/></span>
    <div class="element">
        <span class="label">Short description</span>
        <span class="field"><textarea name="sh_description" rows="5" cols="15"></textarea></span>
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <span class="label">Task description</span>
        <span class="field"><textarea name="description" rows="5" cols="15" id="htmlarea"></textarea></span>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

this is the tinyMCE initialisation :

```
    tinyMCE.init({

        // General options
        theme : "simple",
        mode : "none",


        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        content_css : "/static/css/tinymce.css",

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url : "/static/js/tinymce/lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "/static/js/tinymce/lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "/static/js/tinymce/lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "/static/js/tinymce/lists/media_list.js",

        // Style formats
        style_formats : [
            {title : 'Bold text', inline : 'b'},
            {title : 'Red text', inline : 'span', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
            {title : 'Red header', block : 'h1', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
            {title : 'Example 1', inline : 'span', classes : 'example1'},
            {title : 'Example 2', inline : 'span', classes : 'example2'},
            {title : 'Table styles'},
            {title : 'Table row 1', selector : 'tr', classes : 'tablerow1'}
        ]

    });
```

and the code for the fancybox initiation :

```
function mceAdd(){
    tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", false, "htmlarea");
}
function mceEnd(){
    tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRemoveControl", false, "htmlarea");

}

$(".taskAdd").fancybox({
    'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
    'transitionIn'      : 'none',
    'transitionOut'     : 'none',
    'onComplete'        : mceAdd,
    'onClosed'          : mceEnd
});
```

all the javascript is being run inside a `$(document).ready()` statement.

i've read through a lot of questions on stackoverflow and i haven't found a solution that works for me. in the current state i get a "`Component returned failure code: 0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED) [nsIDOMHTMLDocument.implementation]`" when the `mceEnd()` function is called.

I get an error in Opera as well as in Firefox. If anyone has any ideas on what i'm doing wrong, they would be greatly appreciated.

**Update :**

Tried Thariama's functions with the following results :
if i don't use anything from the fancybox ( just open it and close it) i get a "`Component returned failure code: 0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED) [nsIDOMHTMLDocument.implementation]`" error, but if i try to change the area ( say, select the bold function and then close the fancybox dialog) i get a "`j is null`" error

Versions used : TinyMCE 3.4.7, jQuery fancybox 1.3.4, jQuery 1.7.1

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds like the editor instance does not get shut down correctly. This is the reason why tinymce does not get initialized the second time you open the form.
You may try this code inside your `mceEnd()` function and tell us what happens

```
for (var i = 0; i < tinymce.editors.length; i++) {
   tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRemoveControl", false, tinymce.editors[i].id);
}
```

**EDIT:** Workaround approach:
I suggest you try the following and tell me if that helps. This should enable you to open the form a second time, but won't remove the js error on `mceEnd()`.

```
// global variable in script on top of the page
var editor_count = 0;

function mceAdd(){
    document.getElementById('htmlarea').setAttribute('id', 'htmlarea'+editor_count);
    tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", false, 'htmlarea'+editor_count);
}

function mceEnd(){
    editor_count++;
    // will throw js-error but hopefully this won't hinder us to reinitialize a second form
    tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRemoveControl", false, "htmlarea"+(editor_count-1) );
}
```

Comment: i get the same error as before. ( Component returned failure code: 0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED) [nsIDOMHTMLDocument.implementation] ) tried doing a console.log to check the id, and it returns the correct one (htmlarea)

Comment: looks like the regular shut down command produces this error no matter what you do. we should try to find a workaround for this.i will update my answer with a workaround approach

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. tried the changes you suggested and i get the results posted in my update

Comment: that "j is null" error sounds familiar to me. what version of tinymce are you using?

Comment: updated initial post with versions used (i'm updating it instead of the comments because they can get lost in the crowd and i'd rather have all the info in one spot for future reference )

Comment: hmm, as far as i remmeber ther e was such a "j is null" problem in one of the early 3.4.x releases of tinymce, but what you are using is the most recent version and this error should have been removed since a few minor versions. For nor i am out of ideas.